# MVC Code First: App_Data Folder Not Being Created

Tags: model-view-controller, iis, sql-server-ce, iis-7.5, app-data

I'm using the MVC Code First approach to create a SQL Compact database (from WebConfig: data source=|DataDirectory|MailBoxDB.sdf).  The .sdf file should get created automatically, and it does if I manually create the App_Data folder on the web server (Windows Server 2008).  However, I'm trying to automate the deployment process and I want to eliminate this manual step.  I'm using MSDeploy to create the deployment package. Is it a permissions issue that prevents IIS (7.5) from creating the App_Data folder on its own? If so, which settings should I be focusing on? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a [similar scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900005/how-do-i-get-msdeploy-to-create-app-data-if-it-doesnt-exist-but-not-delete-any/8931695) (generally more complex, although without a database in App_Data).  I pieced together several SO questions and found a solution which I've posted on my question on the same topic.  Take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8931695/113225) and hopefully it helps.